# Parse-JS-SDK: Facebook-Login iOS webapp

Tags: ios, facebook, web-applications, authentication, parse-platform

I'm trying to develop a webapp for iOS using the [Parse-SDK](https://parse.com/).
When I save my app to the homescreen and press the button to login via facebook, it shows just a white screen.

I know this was asked several times, and a solution for the standard facebook-sdk is to add `display : 'touch'` to the FB.login-function.

But with parse-sdk I have to use this function:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
      appId      : 'APP_ID', // Facebook App ID
      status     : true,  // check Facebook Login status
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
      xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
      version    : 'v2.3' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
    });

    $('body').on('click', '#facebookLogin', function() {

        Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn("email", {
          success: function(user) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
          },
          error: function(user, error) {
            alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
          }
        });

    });

  };
```

So I can't add the option `display : 'touch'`. Does anyone know how to fix the white screen?

Thanks.